# STM32 HAL_DELAY hangs with HAL_GetTick=0

Tags: c, stm32, embedded, hal-library

Environment: GNU_ARM, STM32F407

Every time I use `hal_delay()` the program hangs just before the call to `hal_delay()`.

I added:

`printf("\n%d==>%d,",tickstart,HAL_GetTick());`

in the loop of HAL_DELAY. The result is always: `0==>0`

`HAL_GetTick()` doesn't work as expected even after I added:

`HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn,0,0);`

How can I solve this?

Comment: the question is not clear, if possible modify the question with some line of code where the fault occur, also give more details of the problem you face

Comment: the problem was that the interrupt is not handled so i added the file stm32f4xx_it.c/h generated by cubemx to my project wich contain a call to hal_inctick()

Comment: Be careful with interrupts

Comment: Not sure what's unclear about the question. The question and answers helped me to fix this issue for me. I had the `HAL_GetTick()` overwritten and forgot to increment `uwTick` in my function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an advanced STM32 user I can say that you did not handle the SysTick interrupt.

The HAL library enables the SysTick timer and interrupts for it.

In stm32f4xx_it.c file add this function call:

```
void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    HAL_IncTick();
}
```

Then it should work.

Comment: sorry where i can find stm32f4xx_it.c i can't find it in the project.

Comment: I assume you use CMSIS lib. If so, this file should be provided by ST. Use CubeMX to generate project for you. Then start from there.

Comment: thx a lot bro it works

Comment: You will not believe how long it took me... to find your (correct) answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you use a HAL_DELAY you have to keep in mind that the counting is done in the interrupt routine SysTick. If you call the HAL_DELAY in the interrupt that has greater priority, then systick counting is stopped. So the HAL_DELAY gets stucked in the endless loop do...while, because the systick isn't counting. The remedy would be to set  Systick interrupt at higher priority.

Comment: https://github.com/MaJerle/stm32fxxx_hal_libraries/blob/master/00-STM32_LIBRARIES/tm_stm32_delay.c#L243

Delay can be easily done in interrupt with higher priority. Systick should always have lowest priority possible.

Comment: @tilz0R I am using the MxCube, is it possible to make a simple patch to the autogenerated code? I see you are using your custom library.

Comment: Cube will always generate this but you can override HAL_Delay I suppose. It has __weak parameter. Since SysTick has flag which indicates that reload happens but you did not read yet status, you can determine number of reloads (number of systicks).